# How to get a Toast Notification when app running in foreground in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, phonegap-pushplugin

I want to implement the "toast" notification inside my windows phone application. I'm implementing push message's, but I want them to show always. No matter if the application is running or not. The push notification will handle it when the application is closed, but not when it is running. Also if I create a shelltoast manually it won't show. To make it more difficult I can't use any external dll's. I only want to use code. What would be the best way to do this? I already know about the ToastNotificationRecieved event. I want to know how to implement it so that it will show a "toast" like message without using a framework

My code is below

PushPlugin.cs(c# code)

```
public void showToastNotification(string options)
    {

        ShellToast toast;
        if (!TryDeserializeOptions(options, out toast))
        {
            this.DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            return;
        }
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(toast.Show);

    }



public void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
        {
 var toast = new PushNotification
            {
                Type = "toast"
            };

            foreach (var item in e.Collection)
            {
                toast.JsonContent.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            this.ExecuteCallback(this.pushOptions.NotificationCallback, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toast));
        }
```

In javascript

```
function onNotificationWP8(data) {
    var pushNotification;
    pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
    pushNotification.showToastNotification(successHandler, errorHandler,
      {
          "Title": data.jsonContent["wp:Text1"], "Content": data.jsonContent["wp:Text2"], "NavigationUri": data.jsonContent["wp:Param"]
      });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

On devices without Windows Phone 8 Update 3, toast notifications are not displayed when the target app is running in the foreground. On devices with Windows Phone 8 Update 3, toast notifications are displayed when the target app is running in the foreground, but is obscured by other activity such as a phone call or the lock screen.

The following C# code example shows the properties used to create a toast notification using local code.

```
// Create a toast notification.
// The toast notification will not be shown if the foreground app is running.
ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
toast.Title = "[title]";
toast.Content = "[content]";
toast.Show();
```

This [thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/jj662938(v=vs.105).aspx) has it all you looking for

Comment: In my code Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(toast.Show); Here actually toast is not showing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class Notification
{
    public static string ChannelURI = string.Empty;

    public static void MainNotificationCallFunction()
    {
        try
        {
            NotificationMessage("Test Notification");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
    }

    public static void NotificationMessage(string Message)
    {
        try
        {
            ToastTemplateType toastType = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

            XmlDocument toastXmlJob = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastType);
            XmlNodeList toastTextElementJob = toastXmlJob.GetElementsByTagName("text");
            toastTextElementJob[0].AppendChild(toastXmlJob.CreateTextNode(Message));
            IXmlNode toastNodeJob = toastXmlJob.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
            ((XmlElement)toastNodeJob).SetAttribute("duration", "long");
            ToastNotification toastJob = new ToastNotification(toastXmlJob);
            ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toastJob);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }
    }

    public static void PushNotification()
    {
        try
        {
            /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
            HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;
            string channelName = "Usman's Channel";

            // Try to find the push channel.
            pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

            // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
            if (pushChannel == null)
            {
                pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

                //// Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
                pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);

                pushChannel.Open();
                pushChannel.BindToShellTile();
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();
            }
            else
            {
                //// The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
                pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<HttpNotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    private static void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // Display the new URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", e.ChannelUri.ToString()));

            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    private static void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}", e.ErrorType, e.Message, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorAdditionalData)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    private static void PushChannel_HttpNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string message;
            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Notification.Body))
            {
                message = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Received Notification {0}:\n{1}", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), message)));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }

    private static void channel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    private static void channel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                //ProgressBarPushNotifications.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                MessageBox.Show(e.ChannelUri.ToString(), "Uri Recieved", MessageBoxButton.OK);
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
    private static void channel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, HttpNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
            string relativeUri = string.Empty;

            message.AppendFormat("Received Toast {0}:\n", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

            using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Notification.Body))
            {
                message.AppendFormat(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }

            // Display a dialog of all the fields in the toast.
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            {
                MessageBox.Show(message.ToString());
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}
```